80's B movie with a reunion and a loan shark
I am trying to find an 80's B movie that I believe went straight to VHS.  
It starts with a school/college reunion and is based around 4 male friends. One of the friends is white haired and looked similar to Steve Martin, and pretends to be blind at the reunion in order to hook up with a woman.  The story continues with the same man on the run from a loan shark and ends up stealing the alumni from the school reunion.  All four of the friends end up on the run from the loan shark, ending up in a place similar to Reno to try and earn more money with the stolen money, they promptly lose a lot of the money.
They somehow end up at a ranch in the desert which is full of expensive prostitutes which they spend more money on and one friend fall in love with one of the woman, If i can remember correct he is very depressed and trying to kill himself by taking to many vitamins because in his own words "It seems like a healthy way to die"
Also to add I think the character of the friend who was faking his blindness at the school reunion was called JACK

You might also want to provide a more descriptive question title

It's possible this is the comedy Glory Years, an HBO TV movie (or mini-series, really) from 1987. It's quite obscure, but the synopsis fits:

A group of former high-school buddies have a reunion in Las Vegas. Thinking to increase their alumni fund, they proceed to use it to gamble at the casinos. Of course, they lose it all. They then get together and try to figure out a way to win it all back.

Also, it's about three male friends, one of the friends is called Jack and he does have white hair and looks a bit like Steve Martin from a distance. Unfortunately, that's kind of all we have to go on. There are no clips online and reviews are scarce. Maybe these posters will jog your memory:




Oh wow! Tawny Kataen! I remember her dancing around on sports cars in that White Snake video. Too funny.
